# Extjs paging toolbar problem

Tags: extjs, extjs4

When I try to show five rows only, the paging toolbar says "showing 1-5 of [however many items I got in db]", the problem is that the grid actually shows the entire db even if it says it shows just the 5 items. This is my store:

```
var viewOrder = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model : 'orderModel',
    pageSize: 5,
    proxy : new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        type : 'ajax',
    url : 'allOrderJson',
    method : 'GET',
    reader : {
        type : 'json',
        root : 'jsonArray',
        totalProperty : 'total'
    }
}),
autoLoad: false,
});
```

the model:

```
Ext.regModel('orderModel', {
    fields : [ {
        name : 'order_number',
        type : 'string'
    }, {
    name : 'status',
    type : 'string'
    }, {
    name : 'time_of_delivery',
    type : 'string'
    }, {
         name : 'last_edited',
         type : 'string'
    } ]
});
```

before I create my grid, I load the store:

```
viewOrder.load({
    params : {
        start : 0,
        limit : 5,
    }
});
```

my grid:

```
xtype : 'grid',
    id : 'incompleteorders',
    title : 'outstanding orders',
    store : viewOrder,

    columns : [ {
        text : 'order number',
        dataIndex : 'order_number',
    }, {
        text : 'status',
        dataIndex : 'status',
    }, {
        text : 'delivery date',
        dataIndex : 'time_of_delivery',
    }, {
        text : 'last edited',
        dataIndex : 'last_edited',
    }, ],
    dockedItems : [ {
        xtype : 'pagingtoolbar',
        pageSize : 5,
        store : viewOrder, 
        dock : 'bottom', 
        displayInfo : true,
        emptyMsg : 'No data to display',
    } ]
```

Can you see if I'm doing something wrong? I tried following the sencha documentation, but obviously that did not work properly.

Comment: Oh and I have tried using bbar instead of dockedItems as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a request gets sent to the server for 5 items, do you only return the 5 items it requests? It's up to you to do the appropriate filtering on the server.

See the totalProperty option here: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.data.reader.Json

The totalProperty refers to the property in your response that contains the total number of records. It defaults to total, so your response should look something like:

```
{
    "total": 20,
    "records": [{
        "a": "foo"
    }]
}
```

In doing so you will also need to set the root property on the reader appropriately, in the example above it would be "records".

Comment: No, I was under the impression that you could have all the data in the store and let ext handle the paging of the data, how else would ext know how many pages there are?

Comment: With risk of sounding stupid; How do I set the totalProperty correctly? the only example I can see anywhere is totalProperty : 'total' - what are my options?

Comment: Right, so tried this out and still have the same issue - Everything in the paging toolbar looks correct but the grid still shows all orders.